# Multiple table queries in SQL

Tags: sql

I have this SQL statement

```
SELECT branchNo, COUNT(staffNo) AS noStaff
FROM Staff
GROUP BY branchNo
HAVING COUNT(staffNo) > 1
ORDER BY branchNo;
```

Which displays the branches and number of staff who work there.

How can I also display the addresses of each branch like the postcode and city?

[Staff Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYOUf.png)

[Branch Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jsPr.png)

Answer (score 0):

if the address is in the same staff, you should add this param into the SELECT statement, you should do something like this

```
SELECT branchNo, COUNT(staffNo) AS noStaff, address, postcode,...
FROM Staff
GROUP BY branchNo
HAVING COUNT(staffNo) > 1
ORDER BY branchNo;
```

But if you want show the address concatenate, you should use the CONCAT function, writing something like this

```
SELECT branchNo, COUNT(staffNo) AS noStaff, CONCAT(address, 'my string', postcode,...)
FROM Staff
GROUP BY branchNo
HAVING COUNT(staffNo) > 1
ORDER BY branchNo;
```

[here the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

but if your data is in another table, you should to use the JOIN statement (LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, FULL JOIN, JOIN) writing something like this

```
SELECT branchNo, COUNT(staffNo) AS noStaff, CONCAT(A.address, 'my string', A.postcode,...)
FROM Staff S LEFT JOIN Address A on S.branchNo = A.branchNo
GROUP BY branchNo
HAVING COUNT(staffNo) > 1
ORDER BY branchNo;
```

[Here the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver15)

Obviusly, to give you the right solution I need for the database structure, but I hope that my answer can help you to build the right query

Comment: i get an error saying no such collumn branchNo

Comment: Probably in the database you haven't the field, you can show every field of a table writing
DESCRIBE Staff.
Viewing the table you can decide how to upgrade the table

Comment: GROUP BY usually requires you to mention all non-aggregate results (may depend on the exact RDMS, which wasn't specified)